# One-hot encode labels in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, one-hot-encoding

I have a set of integers from a label column in a CSV file -  `[1,2,4,3,5,2,..]`. The number of classes is `5` ie range of `1` to `6`. I want to one-hot encode them using the below code.

```
y = df.iloc[:,10].values
y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes = 5)
y
```

But this code gives me an error

```
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical` to one-hot the label vector, the integers should start from `0` to `num_classes`, [source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical#args). In your case, you should do as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([1,2,4,3,5,2,4,2,1])
y_tf = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(a-1, num_classes = 5)
y_tf

array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

or, you can use `pd.get_dummies`,

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([1,2,4,3,5,2,4,2,1])
a_pd = pd.get_dummies(a).astype('float32').values 
a_pd

array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```