# Keras binary classification different dataset same prediction results

Tags: c#, keras, classification

I have 2 values for predict label, -1 or 1.
The learning looks good with `LSTM` or with `Dense`, but the prediction is always the same with different predict datasets, changing the layers to Dense does not change the prediction, maybe I am doing something wrong.

Here is the code

```
// set up data arrays
float[,,] training_data = new float[training.Count(), 12, 200];
float[,,] testing_data = new float[testing.Count(), 12, 200];
float[,,] predict_data = new float[1, 12, 200];

IList<float> training_labels = new List<float>();
IList<float> testing_labels = new List<float>();

// Load Data and add to arrays
...
...

/////////////////////////
NDarray train_y = np.array(training_labels.ToArray());
NDarray train_x = np.array(training_data);

NDarray test_y = np.array(testing_labels.ToArray());
NDarray test_x = np.array(testing_data);

NDarray predict_x = np.array(predict_data);

train_y = Util.ToCategorical(train_y, 2);
test_y = Util.ToCategorical(test_y, 2);

//Build functional model
var model = new Sequential();

model.Add(new Input(shape: new Keras.Shape(12, 200)));
model.Add(new BatchNormalization());

model.Add(new LSTM(128, activation: "tanh", recurrent_activation: "sigmoid", return_sequences: false));            
model.Add(new Dropout(0.2));
model.Add(new Dense(32, activation: "relu"));            
model.Add(new Dense(2, activation: "softmax"));

model.Compile(optimizer: new SGD(), loss: "binary_crossentropy", metrics: new string[] { "accuracy" });
model.Summary();

var history = model.Fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size: 1, epochs: 1, verbose: 1, validation_data: new NDarray[] { test_x, test_y });

var score = model.Evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose: 2);
Console.WriteLine($"Test loss: {score[0]}");
Console.WriteLine($"Test accuracy: {score[1]}");

NDarray predicted=model.Predict(predict_x, verbose: 2);
                    
Console.WriteLine($"Prediction: {predicted[0][0]*100}");
Console.WriteLine($"Prediction: {predicted[0][1]*100}");
```

And this is the ouput

```
    483/483 [==============================] 
    - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.1989 - accuracy: 0.9633 - val_loss: 0.0416 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
      4/4 - 0s - loss: 0.0416 - accuracy: 1.0000
    Test loss: 0.04155446216464043
    Test accuracy: 1
    1/1 - 0s

    Prediction: 0.0010418787496746518
    Prediction: 99.99896287918091
```

The same predict data used in ML.net gives a different results, but with ML.Net the accuracy is only 0.6, that's why I need a deep learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) set up to reproduce your code. But I see one small issue that you may need to consider (not sure if this caused the trouble). According to your above code set up, I think you're using the wrong `loss` function for training. As you set,

```
Util.ToCategorical(train_y, 2);
model.Add(new Dense(2, activation: "softmax"));
```

Then your loss function should be `'categorical_crossentropy'` and should be not `'binary_crossentropy'`. Because, you transformed your labels (-1, 1) to a one-hot encoded vector and set `softmax` activation in your last layer.

However, as you said, your labels are -1 and 1; so if you treat your problem as a binary classification problem, then the set up should be something like as follows:

```
# Util.ToCategorical(train_y, 2); # no transformation 
model.Add(new Dense(1, activation: "sigmoid"));
model.compile(..., loss: "binary_crossentropy" )
```

Reference.

- [Neural Network and Binary classification Guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67467084/9215780)
- [Selecting loss and metrics for Tensorflow model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67851641/9215780)

## Update

Here I will give some working demo code for better understanding. But before that, here is one small note. Let's say, we have a training data set and labels start from `< 0` or minus value, `[-2, -1, 0, 1]` for example. And to transform this integer value into a one-hot encoded vector, we can pick either `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical` or `pd.get_dummies` function. But a small difference between these two methods is, in `tf..to_categorical`, our integer label must start from `0`; which is not in the case of `pd.get_dummies`, please check my [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67546389/9215780) on this. Shortly,

```
np.random.randint(-1, 1, size=(80))
array([-1, -1,  0,  0,  0 .. ]

pd.get_dummies(a).astype('float32').values[:5] 
array([[1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]], dtype=float32)

tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(a+1, num_classes = 2)[:5]
array([[1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Okay, I'm giving now some working demo code.

```
img = tf.random.normal([80, 32], 0, 1, tf.float32)
tar = pd.get_dummies(np.random.randint(-1, 1,  # mine: [-1, 1) - yours: [-1, 1]
                                       size=80)).astype('float32').values 

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_dim = 32, 
                       kernel_initializer ='normal', 
                       activation= 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(img, tar, epochs=10, verbose=2)
```

```
Epoch 1/10
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.7610 - accuracy: 0.4375
Epoch 2/10
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.7425 - accuracy: 0.4375
....
Epoch 8/10
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.6694 - accuracy: 0.5125
Epoch 9/10
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.6601 - accuracy: 0.5750
Epoch 10/10
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.6511 - accuracy: 0.5750
```

**Inference**

```
loss, acc = model.evaluate(img, tar); print(loss, acc)
pred = model.predict(img); print(pred[:5])

3ms/step - loss: 0.6167 - accuracy: 0.7250
0.6166597604751587 0.7250000238418579

# probabilities of the predicted labels -1 and 0
[[0.35116166 0.64883834]
 [0.5542663  0.4457338 ]
 [0.28023133 0.71976864]
 [0.5024315  0.49756846]
 [0.41029742 0.5897026 ]]
```

Now, if we do

```
print(pred[0])
pred[0].argmax(-1) # expect: -1, 0 as our label 

[0.35116166 0.64883834]
1
```

It gives `0.35x` and `0.64x` for the target label `-1` and `0` respectively.  But, when we did `.argmax` for the predicted **label** from probabilities, it returns zero-indexed highest values; (a reason to make the training labels start from zero indexes, and so I think in your case it's better to transform `[-1, 1]` to `[0, 1]`).

Okay, lastly, as you mentioned that, you want predicted label and corresponding confidences scores; and to do that, we can use [tf.math.top_k](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/top_k) with `k = num_of_class`.

```
top_k_values, top_k_indices = tf.math.top_k(pred, k=2)
for values, indices in zip(top_k_values, top_k_indices):
    print(
        'For class {}, model confidence {:.2f}%'
        .format(indices.numpy()[0]-1, values.numpy()[0]*100)
        )
    
    print(
        'For class {}, model confidence {:.2f}%'
        .format(indices.numpy()[1]-1, values.numpy()[1]*100)
        )
    
    '''
    Note: above we substract -1 to match with 
          the target label (-1, 0)

    And it would not necessary if we initially -
    transform our label from (-1, 0) to (0, 1), i.e. start from zero 
    '''
    print()
    break # remove for full results
```

```
For class 0, model confidence 64.88%
For class -1, model confidence 35.12%
```

Verifying the score order

```
# pick first samples: input and label
model(img)[0].numpy(), tar[0]

(array([0.35116166, 0.64883834], dtype=float32),
 array([0., 1.], dtype=float32))

Here, 
0: for -1
1: for 0

# Again, better to transform (-1, 0) to (0, 1) at initial.
```

Comment: Thanks, I did as you said and now I get different prediction results, but only one value is present at predicted[0][0], predicted[0][1] is null. With one data I got the result 20.3 and with a different data I got 12.2, how can I interpret this data to my -1 and 1 result? Also the result changes even if don't change the data. Thanks!

Comment: Changing to categorical_crossentropy I get the same results again, Prediction: 0.06129330722615123
Prediction: 99.93870258331299

Comment: For my first comment, I also tried predicted[0] and predicted[1], the first value is the same  and the second is null.

Comment: I need the predicted results something like this (-1) 30% probability,  (1) 70% probability

Comment: I didn't know that the category values must start from 0, I will try that. I'm still trying to understand the code, because it is a little different from C# also not all Keras functions from Python are implemented in C# Keras, especially from numpy

Comment: I see. Let me know if I need to break through any of my coding parts. I wish I could answer in C#. However, the basics should be the same, that's sure. You can run my code on colab easily and verify each and every aspect.

Comment: I don't understand what the [:5] does? from this line pd.get_dummies(a).astype('float32').values[:5] this is not present in C#

Comment: `[:5]` is called array [slicing in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp). It's not an important thing for you. I used it for **checking purposes**. Like, when I used `print(pred[:5])`, it means to print out the first 5 elements or **probabilities score of the first 5 samples**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234651/discussion-between-m-innat-and-mario-m).

Comment: please go to the chatbox, I wrote some responses;  please check.